# In Nginx what is the resolver directive mechanically doing to avoid errors and warnings?

Tags: nginx, domain-name-system, internal-dns

**Environment:** Nginx, Node.js

I've read the [Nginx Docs on Resolver](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#resolver), I understand it's used for DNS and I include it in my config.
However I don't entirely understand what it's doing or when and why I need it.

In the simplified config below when I turn on the nginx and node.js servers and request pages in the browser everything works as expected and no warnings or errors are thrown.  The IP addresses I'm using in `resolver` are google's public DNS servers.

```
http {

    resolver 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 [2001:4860:4860::8888] [2001:4860:4860::8844];

    server {

        listen 443 ssl http2;
        listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

        server_name example.com;

        ssl_stapling on;
        ssl_stapling_verify on;
        ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/chain.pem;

        root /srv/example/views/public;

        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        }

    }

}
```

However when I remove `resolver 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 [2001:4860:4860::8888] [2001:4860:4860::8844];` boot the servers and request pages I get a warning in my error.log.  At the same time everything works fine in the browser and no error or warning is sent to the client.

> 2020/12/11 20:04:24 [warn] 1191#1191: no resolver defined to resolve
> r3.o.lencr.org while requesting certificate status, responder:
> r3.o.lencr.org, certificate:
> "/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem"

It's easy enough to keep the reference to Google's DNS servers as my `resolver` value and avoid the warning but I'm not entirely sure what is happening.  Because I don't know what this directive is doing I'm not entirely sure if Google's DNS servers are the correct choice.  I believe I only need `resolver` if I'm also using the `proxy_pass` directive but I'm not entirely sure of that.

**Question:** What is resolver doing and when is it called or not called?  I understand it's performing DNS but I'm not sure when or why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You asked for `ssl_stapling`, which requires contacting the OCSP responder listed in your TLS certificate. A `resolver` is needed to get the IP address from its name.

Comment: I used google's DNS servers in my config.  Is that as good as any other or alternately is there a reason I should choose a different DNS?

Comment: @stackedAndOverflowed It just needs to be reliable.